# Track screen rendering traces for a Flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase-performance

How to track rendering traces? Drop down menu doesn’t offer me any of my screens, only Android activities.
[image]

I use `setCurrentScreen()` function to tell Firebase my current screen.